# Playframework 2.1.2 QueryStringBindable objects Pager/MeterLimitVal not binding querystrings when routed from template to controller as a parameter

Tags: java, playframework, query-string

I tried with my own class MeterLimitVal and with less complex example [Pager](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/test/integrationtest-java/app/controllers/Pager.java) class. The bind method doesn't work correctly, because it's Map parameter is null. I am able to see that from the debug checks I put to bind method. As a result I get Bad request error message.

```
@Override
public F.Option<Pager> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {
    //if (data.containsKey(key + ".index") && data.containsKey(key + ".size")) {
    //    try {
            System.out.println("Pager: bind()");
            System.out.println("Pager: bind() key > " + key);
            System.out.println("Pager: bind() data > " + data);
            index = Integer.parseInt(data.get(key + ".index")[0]);
            size = Integer.parseInt(data.get(key + ".size")[0]);
            System.out.println("Pager: bind() > index, size > " + index + ", " + size);
            return F.Option.Some(this);
    ...
}
```

I implemented Pager class exactly in the same way as previous link, then got rid of ..data.containsKey checks in bind method, that's the reason why I get Bad requests, otherwise F.Option.None() is returned.

I create Pager object in my controller's method pipeIndex and then at the end of this method I pass that object to return value:

```
return ok(views.html.pipeIndex.render(pager1, ...);
```

Here's the important parts of pipeIndex template(pipeIndex.scala.html):

```
@(pager1: models.Pager, ...)
...
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="@routes.Application.indexResults(0, "pipe_consequence_index", "desc", pager1)" method="GET">
...
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="@Messages("calculate.index")" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

part of routes file:

```
GET     /indexResults           controllers.Application.indexResults(p:Int ?= 0, s ?= "pipe_consequence_index", o ?= "desc", pager1:models.Pager)
```

When clicking the button the application is supposed to show the indexResults page, but I get Bad request error message.

I tried to search Playframework's integration test pages for an example. From the [unit test class](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9206bea8c9c88acdc6786ebb2554f081396e8f6a/framework/test/integrationtest-java/test/controllers/BindablesTest.java) I learned using Call class and put it to my Controller's method pipeIndex where I create Pager class:

```
Pager pager1 = new Pager();
Call call = routes.Application.indexResults(0, "pipe_consequence_index", "desc", pager1);
System.out.println("Call URL > " + call.url());
```

This shows the call URL in the expected way:

```
Call URL > /indexResults?pager1.index=45&pager1.size=313
```

When I try to hack the address line in my browser, I am able to get into indexResults page.

```
http://localhost:9000/indexResults?pager1.index=0&pager1.size=0
```

Somehow the parameters going to bind method doesn't go in the correct way (null :( ), when indexResults is called from template. Did you see that kind of problem? Can you help me?

Cheers,
Alparslan